# Access Active Directory username on web page

Tags: web, intranet

On our intranet, I want to provide a website that certain employees can access.  The work they do on the site will be recorded and tagged with their user-name for identification if the need should arise.  Of course users have already logged in to their workstation and they have supplied credentials to our Active Directory.

Rather than maintain an additional set of user logins and passwords for the website, and forcing users to enter this second set of credentials, I am wondering if they can just be silently authenticated when they pull up the site?  Somehow the webpage would have to find out their Active Directory user name as known on their workstation.  (I see no reason it would need their password.)  And then, for their work, the website can store their actions tagged with their user name.

So:  I'd log in to my workstation as "Mark" in domain "ONU-AD".  I'd pull up the webpage "resolveticket.php".  That page would not challenge me for credentials, but it can access my username and store that with my various actions.

NOTE: I have seen some questions and answers here that were more specific.  But my initial question is general: is there a piece of tech that can help with this?  What is it?  (for example, should I try to do this with Java?)  Many similar questions are about ways to get this information in a server-side script.  But I am simply wanting the webpage sitting on the client computer to be able to get the user name and perhaps place it in an input (type="hidden") on a web form.

Comment: Active Directory Federation Services - MSDN - Microsoft

Comment: Thanks, Sorceri, this looks interesting, and I did not know about it.  In my current environment, the website is on a Linux/Apache/PHP setup, not Windows/IIS.  That could be changed, but I'm wondering whether ADFS can be used by such an environment.  I see some articles about it from a Google search, I will look into those.